# How can i use the database sqlite in my application?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I'm trying to connect the database with my system but always after call the function shows like this in apliccation's browser:

[The "granjas" table is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3BqO.png)

Here's the code:

ON JS:

```
var db = openDatabase("Meubanco", "3.0", "Mybase", 6000);
db.transaction(function(criar){
  criar.executeSql("CREATE TABLE granjas (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nome TEXT, email TEXT, cnpj TEXT)");
});

function cadastrar(){

var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var cnpj = document.getElementById("cnpj").value;

db.transaction(function(armazenar){
   armazenar.executeSql("INSERT INTO granjas (nome, email, cnpj) VALUES (?,?@email.com,?)", [nome, email, cnpj]);
   alert("Granja " + document.getElementById("nome").value + " Cadastrada!");
  });
};
```

AND ON HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="cadastrar();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="nome">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereço de email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>CNPJ</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" placeholder="cnpj">
  </div>
  <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Insira uma imagem da granja<small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ação Opcional.</small></label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="imagem_da_empresa"/>
  </div>
  </form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cadastrar();">Cadastrar</button>
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" href="listagem_de_granjas.html">Granjas Cadastrdas</a>
</form>
```

I think it is clear what i want to do. Here's a link to the project: https://github.com/Nidhoggui/beta-_projetoavicultura

Comment: In browser's developer tools click on the `Network` tab on the left from `Application`. Is there any error with submitting data into the database?

Comment: No, it just doesn't send the data to database

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

`email?email.com` is causing the problem in

```
armazenar.executeSql("INSERT INTO granjas (nome, email?email.com, cnpj) VALUES (?,?,?)", [nome, email, cnpj])
```

**Explanation**

Function `.executeSql()` accepts success and error callbacks - You can use them to see if `.executeSql()` was executed correctly:

```
armazenar
   .executeSql(
       "INSERT INTO granjas (nome, email, cnpj) VALUES (?,?email.com,?)",
       [nome, email, cnpj], 
       function() { console.log("SUCCESS") }, 
       function(data, error) { console.log("There was an ERROR", error) });
```

The code above will output this error into the console:

```
SQLError {code: 5, message: "could not prepare statement (1 near "@email": syntax error)"}code: 5message: "could not prepare statement (1 near "@email": syntax error)"__proto__: SQLError
```

**Solution**

```
function cadastrar(){
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value + '@email.com';
  var cnpj = document.getElementById("cnpj").value;

  db.transaction(function(armazenar){
    armazenar
       .executeSql(
           "INSERT INTO granjas (nome, email, cnpj) VALUES (?,?,?)",
           [nome, email, cnpj], 
           function() { 
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                alert("Granja " + document.getElementById("nome").value + " Cadastrada!");
            }, 
           function(data, error) { 
                console.log("There was an ERROR", error) 
                alert("There was a technical error. Try again.");
            });
  }); 
};
```